# Is there a way to make the band in the DevExpress Banded GridView be invisible if all the columns are also invisible?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am currently using a DevExpress (10.2) Banded GridView within my Visual Studio 2010 project. It works great except I was have an area where I allow the user to choose which columns they want visible or invisible. I noticed that if I make all the columns within a band invisible the band still remains and gives an empty column in my grid. I was wondering if there is some way to automatically make the band invisible if all of it's subcolumns are invisible and also reverse if one or more columns are set to visible to set the band visible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to handle it in the designer but, you could use something like this:

```
If GridBand1.Columns.VisibleColumnCount = 0 Then
    GridBand1.Visible = False
Else
    GridBand1.Visible = True
End If
```

I tested it in the ColumnPositionChanged Event of the grid view, and it worked fine for hiding the band when I removed a column.  I would think it should also work in combination with your code for allowing hiding/displaying of specific columns instead of that event.

Comment: I will have to try that come Monday. Thank you for your help.